# Vb.Net Writing a sub in the parameter when calling a method

Tags: vb.net

I have written some code where i perform an action in my method's parameter:

```
_myService.MyMethod(userId, profileId, Sub(message As EventArgs) _eventAggregator.SendMessage(message))
```

This is the Method thats being called:

```
Public Sub MyMethod(userId As Guid, profileId As Guid, ByVal action As Action(Of EventArgs))
    Dim proxy = BuildProxy()

    AddHandler proxy.MyMethodCompleted, Sub(o, e) action(e)

    Using New OperationContextScope(proxy.InnerChannel)
        Dim request = New MyMethodRequest() With {.gebruikerId = userId, .omgevingsId = omgevingId}
        proxy.MyMethodAsync(request)
    End Using
End Sub
```

Now i want to extend the Sub passed to my service method to include:

```
_myService.MyMethod(userId, profileId, Sub(message As EventArgs) _eventAggregator.SendMessage(message)
_localVariable = e.Result
End Sub)
```

This obviously doens't work. Is this possible?

Comment: A word on indentation and line breaks in VB to make the code more readable (on Github since the comment is too short): https://gist.github.com/klmr/5003412

Comment: @KonradRudolph thnx :)

Answer (score 1):

Found it allready. Switching from c# to vb.net isn't always easy ;)

```
_myService.MyMethod(userId, profileId, Sub(message As EventArgs) 
    _eventAggregator.SendMessage(message)
    _localVariable = e.Result
    End Sub)
```

Just had to hit next line after my sub ....